# How to iterate and unzip list of files present in a input txt file using windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an **input.txt** which contains list of files.

Some of them have **.7z** extension (zipped using 7zip) and some of them dont.

**Content of input.txt**: (this list could contain N number of lines and any number of file extensions)

mydir/dir1/dir2/dir3/**A.7z**
mydir/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/B.h
mydir/dir1/dir2/dir4/C.h
mydir/dir1/dir2/**D.7z**

**Notice:**

1. The direction of slashes in input.txt is correct ( i.e., / ).
2. I want to traverse input.txt and unzip files wherever applicable (in this case, unzip A.7z and D.7z)

**My root directory looks like this:**

C:\X\input.txt

C:\X\mybat.bat

C:\X\mydir\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\B.h

C:\X\mydir\dir1\dir2\dir3\A.7z

C:\X\mydir\dir1\dir2\dir4\C.h

C:\X\mydir\dir1\dir2\D.7z

**My script (mybat.bat) looks like this:**

```
@echo off
set filename=%~1
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %filename%') do (
    set z=%%a   
    Set filename2=!z!

    For %%A in ("!filename2!") do (
        Set Folder=%%~dpA
        Set Name=%%~nxA
    )
    echo.Folder is: !Folder!
    echo.Name is: !Name!
    echo.
    echo.
    cd !Folder!
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x !Name!
)
```

**Running script like this:**

> **mybat.bat** input.txt

Issue is: It is correctly unzipping 1st item (i.e., "mydir/dir1/dir2/dir3/A.7z"), but it is failing there after (i.e., unable to unzip remaining list).

Can you please help.

All I want is to be able to traverse input.txt and unzip files (wherever applicable).

Comment: `... in ('type "%filename%" ^| findstr /le ".7z"') do ...`. I expect `7z.exe` to have difficulties unzipping `.h` files.

Comment: if we try to unzip .h files, 7z.exe reports error. That is okay. We can ignore it. Goal is to be able to unzip .7z files.

Comment: Any idea @Stephan how to achieve this goal?

Comment: What is the inner `for %%A` loop intended for? As of my understanding it is useless, so remove it, specify `DisableDelayedExpansion`, remove assignment of variable `z` and simply use `%%~dpa` to get the parent directory (with `\ `at the end) of the currently iterated item and `%%~nxa` for its name; you may want to implement a check like `if /I "%%~xa"==".7z" …`…

Comment: @aschipfl, can you please help me with the script? I am novice in scripting.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /le ".7z" "%~1"') do (
  "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -aoa -o"%%~dpA" "%%~nxA"
)
```

Some explanations:

- it doesn't make sense to create environment variables when you can simply use the `for` metavariables.
- it doesn't make sense to process non-zip files, so I process only `.7z` files.
- the second `for` isn't needed at all.
- no need to `cd` into the destination folder; `7z` has an option to specify the destination folder.

Note the `-aoa` switch (overwrite mode) - adapt or remove it according to your requirements.